# I lack confidence vs I am lacking in confidence?

Tags: meaning, prepositions, present-participles, continuous, stative-verbs

1. I lack confidence
2. I am lacking in confidence

What's the difference in meaning between the two?
Also, does *lacking* place emphasis on present state of lackingness (partial continuity)

Is there a vessel of in where confidence is reduced for stative verb *lack*

Answer (score 1):

> I lack confidence.

This sentence is in the simple present and is more direct and forceful than:

> I am lacking confidence.

...which is in the present progressive tense. The second construction is often used to "pad" the speaker's meaning and is less direct.

Taking this into consideration, "I lack confidence" may be considered mildly ironic, as the simple present exudes confidence.

> I am lacking in confidence.

With the "in", this means "I am deficient in the quality called confidence." It means essentially the same as the first two, but is one step further from a direct statement.

Stylistically, I would prefer not to see the version with "in" since the second version works just as well, rendering the "in" unnecessary unless you are going for a particular effect.

Answer (score 0):

I lack in confidence defines how a person feels.  He is not confident about something.  I am lacking in confidence means that at the moment I don't feel confident enough to do something.